# How to delete duplicate values in a column in MS Access via SQL or VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is there any kind of VBA or SQL which i could run on this table which delete duplicate ID's within MS Access?

So this:

```
ID          data1   data2   data3   
a           1       2       3   
a           8       9       10  
a           15      16      17  
a           22      23      24  
b           1       2       3   
b           8       9       10  
b           15      16      17  
b           22      23      24  
b           29      30      31  
c           1       2       3   
c           8       9       10  
c           15      16      17  
c           22      23      24  
c           29      30      31  
c           36      37      38
```

Would look like this :

```
ID      data1   data2   data3   
a        1      2       3   
         8      9       10  
         15     16      17  
         22     23      24  
b        1      2       3   
         8      9       10  
         15     16      17  
         22     23      24  
         29     30      31  
c        1      2       3   
         8      9       10  
         15     16      17  
         22     23      24  
         29     30      31  
         36     37      38
```

Comment: You could SUM UP all the data columns and place the results into a temporary table. Then delete all from the main table and place the temp table back into the main table.

Comment: I need to display all of the individual records, I just need to remove the duplicates for the first and last name for readability

Comment: Ah ok thats fairly straight forward if you dont actually need to remove them but just create a view. Ill post a SQL statment in a bit.

Comment: It sounds a little bit strange though. Why delete duplicates on first + last name? What will you do when there are two persons having the same name? Chances are close to nothing, but it's just a principle that uniqueness is indicated with a unique primary key (eg. ID), unless you choose to use a composite PK (which is generally not advised in this case). The question is how you accidentally enter doubles INTO the table into the first place, this should not be possible IMO.

Comment: OK, well could we do delete duplicate unique ids? Ill edit the question to have unique ids instead of first and last names.

Comment: I think he just wants a view to make it more readable. He doesnt actually want to delete the duplicate names.

Comment: Delete or hide....whatever works for readability

Comment: Sorry, I didn't watch your example carefully as it was lunch break. Do you want it in Excel or Access? In access, you should not have doubles on your ID if it is a PK, that's one thing. If you want to hide the ID, you should look into reports, but not hide it in the table (!). If you export it to Excel (as you indicated in your previous question), check my reply (your previous question), and if you want I can give you additional code to erase the doubles in the Excel cells.

Comment: @AntonHughes: I'm quite sure that you do **NOT** want to *delete* the values, you just want to *hide* them. If so, *where* do you want to hide them? It's quite easy to hide them in an Access report (using the "Hide Duplicates" property on a Text Box control), but other places in Access hiding the dups is just not possible.

Comment: I am gathering the data into a table via queries in ms access to make the table look like the first table above, then I am exporting it to excel to look like the second table above. I know you can do conditional formating, but i would need to do that within the MS Access VBA code as I need it to be automated, not manually done every time

Comment: Do you have any unique field on your table?

Comment: Yes, but the ID field is not the primary key, I have another primary which i do not need to display in the excel sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should clear the `ID` column of all but the first record. You may want to amend the `ORDER BY` to also include another column to ensure this code runs in the same order as your export after.

```
Dim strKey as String
Dim iCount as Integer
Dim dbs as DAO.Database
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset

strKey = ""
iCount = 0
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY ID")
If rst.RecordCount > 0
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
         If strKey <> rst!ID Then
             strKey = rst!ID
             iCount = 1
         End If

         If iCount > 1 Then
             rst.Edit
                 rst!ID = ""
             rst.Update
         End If

         iCount = iCount + 1
         rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: See where you state rst!ID, what if the field name contains a space.....ie rst!Last name. How would you format that? I have tried [Last name] 'Last Name' '[Last name]'. Or is it just impossible?

Comment: It is still saying that the item is not found in the collection.....i think your right about the `rst.Fields("Last name")` statement....anything else? My SQL statement is `Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblReportFollowUpCallResponses ORDER BY '[Last name]';")`

Comment: Your code works perfect for fields with no spaces....strange that it wont work with fields that do have spaces....:/ any ideas?

Comment: It's the `'[Last name]'` bit. Change it to `[Last name]` (no single-quotes). What line gets the error? Another thing you could try is replacing the `*` in the SQL with `[Last name]` (again, no single-quotes) in case it's not finding that column, and then the error will generate on that line.

Answer (score 3):

you can use view as

```
select distinct First Name , Last Name from T1
```

and save this query as V1
then  you have now first name and last name without duplicate

now use code

```
select * from V1 , T1 where V1.First Name =T1.First Name and V1.Last Name=T1.Last Name
```

I hope this help you an question you have

Comment: This is outputing duplicate rows still within the first and last name.....I need to hide or delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your first name, last name and a sum of all data associated with that first and last name on a single row.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, sum(data1), sum(data2), sum(data3)
FROM MyTableName
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

This would give you something like below:

```
First Name  Last Name   data1   data2   data3   
a           z           46      50       54   
b           x           75      80       85
```

Comment: I don't need the sum, I need to just hide the duplicate names while keeping each row

Comment: You wont be able to do that via SQL query. Sorry. Someone who knows VBA might be able to help.